# Configuring Identity Provider when installing an app

Tags: saml

I'm wondering if its possible to configure Saleforce as an Identity Provider during a Saleforce App installation.

I have an external application that will extract data from Salesforce. I would like for my user to be able to connect using SAML to my application and Salesforce will be the IdentityProvider.

In order to simplify my SaleForce App installation i would like to configure the Identity Provider for my customer if its not already configured.

Comment: "App installation"... Do you mean a managed package?

Comment: Either managed and unmanaged. I'm making a preliminary assessment of what Salesforce can and can't do. That way i'll know the best way to integrate Salesforce to my solution. I want it to be easy for my customer to Salesforce as an Identity Provider so my external application can use it.

Answer (score 0):

SAML and Identity Provider services are really built for internal single sign-on browser based flow. It sounds like you'd be better served by creating a Connected Application for your service and connecting to your users' orgs with OAuth 2.0.